# The application is frozen after using BackgroundWorker C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I read data from file and write them in other file. I want show user number of read lines with label. It working. And user can stop reading. I use backgroundworke, but the application does not respond to the Stop button-is frozen. I tried Aplication.DoEvents(),  But I must just need to button 2x to respond.

start reading

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string ext = Path.GetExtension(openFileDialog1.FileName);
    if (ext == ".arff")
    {
        getColumn();
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
}
```

reading and writing

```
private void readDataArffBig()
{            
    int lines = 0;
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(tempFile, true);
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName))
    {
        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            lines++;
            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(lines);
            if (status == false)
                break;
            sw.WriteLine(line)}
        }
}
```

stop reading set status to false..berofe is true

```
private void stop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    status = false;           
}
```

BW use

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    readDataArffBig();
}

private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    label8.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString();
    label8.Refresh();
}
```

Comment: could you post your click events? this is most likely where the issue lies. The backgroundworker may not be shutting down correctly.

Comment: How many lines are in the file you are reading? You may be flooding the UI thread with too many updates if it is a file with say 10k lines. Also, your `StreamWriter` should be in a `using` statement.

Comment: the files are big over 1GB

Comment: since your files are that big, it could be what @mikez is saying.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, are you setting your `BackgroundWorker` to allow cancellation?

```
backgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
```

Then your `Do_Work` event should look something like this:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
     BackgroundWoker bgw = sender as BackgroundWorker;
    if(bgw.CancellationPending)
    {
       e.Cancel = true;
       return;
    }
    else
    {
      readDataArffBig();
    }
}
```

***EDIT

```
private void stop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
        //status = false;           
    }
```

Comment: I agree that using the built-in cancellation mechanism would be better but this only checks for cancellation *before* starting the operation. The OP needs to modify the loop of `readDataArffBig` to check for cancellation requests as well.

Comment: but the UI still does not respond..I can't click on stop button

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the changes proposed by SOfanatic, and as suggested by mike z, you should be checking for the pending cancellation in readDataArffBig().  A good place would be right in the while statement:

```
while (((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null) && (!backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending))
```